# FHIR Vonk Server - When to use Storage

Tags: hl7-fhir

Just getting started with [Vonk server](https://fire.ly/vonk/).

I'm curious to know, under what circumstances do we need to persist FHIR resources in FHIR Server's storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You persist the resources in a storage when you want to be able to retrieve and/or use the data later.

It is up to you whether you do that with Vonk as a generic server - i.e. Vonk with its own storage, or with Vonk as a Facade to your back-end storage system. That greatly depends on use case, access to and availability of back-end systems, and design of the architecture, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering in detail. I see your edit where you mentioned DSTU2 is not supported. But here https://fire.ly/vonk/ it is stated that 'DSTU2 support is also possible'

Comment: Yes, support is possible, but we are not focusing on DSTU2 at this time. Your question was not about the FHIR version, that is why I asked to remove the dstu2 tag.